# Tachograph Service Card ISO 7816

Tags: smartcard, iso-7816-4

[Tachograph Service Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWmRb.jpg)

I know the password of the card. I want to remove the password. How can I do that?

I'm waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While according to ISO 7816-4 there is the command *Disable Verification Requirement* I doubt that its support is mandated by Tachograph specification. And for a serious security architecture it is unlikely, that knowledge of the PIN alone is sufficient to allow disabling itself.

Comment: But the tachograph device can both write and read the driver card.

Comment: @EmirKorkmaz: This just means, that a different access rule may be defined, which also allows access. It des not imply, that the tachograph device disables the PIN and even if it did, it is unlikely that you are able to mimic this.